# Как стилизовать option(placeholder) у select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно что бы первый `option` элемент был стилизован, что бы он служил как `placeholder`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.select-style {
  position: relative;
  width: 62%;
}
.select-style__select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  height: 3.125rem;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.select-style__select:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-style__select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
.select-style__placeholder {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #636363;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.select-style__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3.375rem;
  background: url(../img/icons/select-arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
   <select name="refine" id="" class="select-style__select">
        <option class="select-style__placeholder">Shipping and Logistics</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
    </select> 
    <div class="select-style__arrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="select-style">
   <select name="spare" id="" class="select-style__select">
        <option class="select-style__placeholder">Shipping and Logistics</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
    </select> 
    <div class="select-style__arrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="select-style">
   <select name="maker" class="select-style__select">
        <option class="select-style__placeholder">Shipping and Logistics</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
        <option value="">text</option>
    </select> 
    <div class="select-style__arrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать что именно первый элемент, потом в скрипте, при изменении `select'a` он будет пропадать, т.е. этот элемент нужен чисто как `placeholder`, пробовал стилизовать как обычный текст, но не получается, какие есть варианты?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, можно, так и сделаю, но все же вопрос остается, как стилизовать этот элемент?

Comment: [может быть это будет полезно](http://www.sitehere.ru/examples/14.01.2015/index2.html)